# PSQL to CSV with column alias leads to corrupted file

Tags: excel, postgresql, csv, copy, psql

I managed to use PSQL on Windows to export a SQL query directly into a CSV file, and everything works fine as long as I don't redefine column names with aliases (using AS).

But as soon as I use a column alias, e.g.:

```
\copy (SELECT    project AS "ID" FROM    mydb.mytable WHERE  project > 15 ORDER BY project)  TO 'C:/FILES/user/test_SQL2CSV.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
```

I have unexpected behaviors with the CSV file.

- In Excel: the CSV is corrupted and is blank
- In Notepad: the data is present, but with no delimiter or spaces
  (continous, e.g. ID27282930...)
- In Notepad++: the data is well organized in a column

(e.g.

```
ID
27
28
29
30
...
```

)

Is there anything to do so that the exported file can be read directly within Excel (as it happens when I don't use aliases)?

Comment: Ok, found the issue, apparently Excel interprets a file starting with ID as some SYLK format instead of CSV... renaming the column alias to e.g. MyID fixed the issue :/ Reference here: https://annalear.ca/2010/06/10/why-excel-thinks-your-csv-is-a-sylk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing various other configurations of the query, I found the issue. Apparently Excel interprets a file starting with "ID" as some SYLK format instead of CSV... Renaming the column alias to e.g. "MyID" fixed the issue.

Reference here: [annalear.ca/2010/06/10/why-excel-thinks-your-csv-is-a-sylk](https://annalear.ca/2010/06/10/why-excel-thinks-your-csv-is-a-sylk/)

Comment: Yup, that's our old friend, Excel. Note that only these two characters `ID` will cause this "corruption"; the quoted variant (i.e. where the file/header starts with `"ID",...`) can be read by Excel. If you can manage to force quotation in the headers (I've never tried that in PostgreSQL's `COPY` command).

Comment: Nice tip, could help down the road, but the main issue wasn't to keep that particular label, but rather to have the aliases working well. Just bad luck with that excel feature :') Thanks anyway!